# Does handler.post(Runnable r) block the MessageQueue?

Tags: android

> A Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects associated with a thread's MessageQueue. Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue. When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, it will deliver messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they come out of the message queue.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Does this actually mean that the Runnable object will block the Messages posted after it?
The messages and Runnable objects actually in one queue?

The manual is little ambiguous to me.

Thanks!

Comment: i think it puts both types in the same Que and will proceed gradually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not so hard to check the code path of this. So in `Activity.java` you have the following code to pass `Runnable` to Ui thread:

```
public final void runOnUiThread(Runnable action) {
    if (Thread.currentThread() != mUiThread) {
        mHandler.post(action);
    } else {
        action.run();
    }
}
```

Then for `Handler.post`:

```
public final boolean post(Runnable r)
{
   return  sendMessageDelayed(getPostMessage(r), 0);
}
```

Basically `sendMessageDelayed` just simply sends a message with delay 0 ms. So the most interesting part is how to `getPostMessage` from Runnable:

```
private final Message getPostMessage(Runnable r) {
    Message m = Message.obtain();
    m.callback = r;
    return m;
}
```

So what does it mean? This means that the handler of the Ui thread if it gets message to run Runnable will try to execute it. And if this runnable operation is very long it will block the Ui thread that can cause ANR error.

Comment: I have checked this, but not in UI thread. The experiment shows that if Runable object sleeped, the last messages just blocked. I just come here to comfort the conclusion. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Yes, of coarse. If handler has started to process runnable that sleeps, this handler will be blocked. That what I wanted to point in my answer.